# Get style reference from customView android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-styles

I have custom view extended from LinearLayout. Inside editText and ImageView.
I want to set custom style for editText

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="custom_view">
        <attr name="editTextStyle" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

<com.test.CustomView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:editTextStyle="@style/CustomEditTextStyle"
    />
```

I am stuck with receiving the style reference inside my CustomView.
How to get style from reference?

will be glad any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow one of the Android views source code.
For example, taken from TextView.java

```
/*
     * Look the appearance up without checking first if it exists because
     * almost every TextView has one and it greatly simplifies the logic
     * to be able to parse the appearance first and then let specific tags
     * for this View override it.
     */
    TypedArray a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextViewAppearance, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    TypedArray appearance = null;
    int ap = a.getResourceId(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextViewAppearance_textAppearance, -1);
    a.recycle();
    if (ap != -1) {
        appearance = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
                ap, com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance);
    }
    if (appearance != null) {
        int n = appearance.getIndexCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int attr = appearance.getIndex(i);

            switch (attr) {
            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColorHighlight:
                textColorHighlight = appearance.getColor(attr, textColorHighlight);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColor:
                textColor = appearance.getColorStateList(attr);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColorHint:
                textColorHint = appearance.getColorStateList(attr);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textColorLink:
                textColorLink = appearance.getColorStateList(attr);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textSize:
                textSize = appearance.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, textSize);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_typeface:
                typefaceIndex = appearance.getInt(attr, -1);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_fontFamily:
                fontFamily = appearance.getString(attr);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textStyle:
                styleIndex = appearance.getInt(attr, -1);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_textAllCaps:
                allCaps = appearance.getBoolean(attr, false);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_shadowColor:
                shadowcolor = appearance.getInt(attr, 0);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_shadowDx:
                dx = appearance.getFloat(attr, 0);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_shadowDy:
                dy = appearance.getFloat(attr, 0);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_shadowRadius:
                r = appearance.getFloat(attr, 0);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_elegantTextHeight:
                elegant = appearance.getBoolean(attr, false);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_letterSpacing:
                letterSpacing = appearance.getFloat(attr, 0);
                break;

            case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextAppearance_fontFeatureSettings:
                fontFeatureSettings = appearance.getString(attr);
                break;
            }
        }

        appearance.recycle();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to reference com.android.internal.R.styleable attributes from your custom view however.